# php Syntax error at first property definition. Appears to be an environment issue. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Tags: php

I am learning php and have put a very simple class definition on my host and am getting syntax errors at the first property definition.

See the first few lines below - the error is

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}'

on the line with the first "public" declaration.

The PHP version is  "5.3.3-7+squeeze13 with Suhosin-Patch".

If I change the "public" to "var", the code gets past this point but dies on some other simple statements (like "throw exception"). Helpful friendly types have claimed that the code works fine in their local development environment.

Any suggestions on what could be happening and how I can fix it? Do I need to migrate my (almost 20 year old) entire website somewhere else?

Thanks.

Code sample:

```
<?php
/* Class name: reBOOKed_User
 * Description: Everthing that a user needs to have associated with them,
 *      including contact information, circle memberships, bookshelves, and
 *      points/pages earned.
 */

class reBOOKed_User
{
    public $Username;
    public $Password;
    public $Emails = array(); #can have multiple emails associated with an account
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running this with PHP 5.3? Because this is valid PHP 5.x syntax (well if you close the class of course) but if I run this with PHP 4.4.9, I get the same error as you.

Comment: See @vstm's comment. Your question is a wee bit unclear as to which PHP version you ran this on and are you saying you have 20 year old PHP code? Can you clarify your question then flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `}` at the end of your file to close the class.

Comment: You scared me, but I checked and have indeed closed the }. I just didn't include it in the snippet here.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't just bad syntax (unbalanced curly braces, for example), then it's usually an indication that your server is actually running an older version of PHP (php 4) that wouldn't support PHP5 code.

PHP4 classes looked like this:

```
class User {
    var $Username;
    var $Password;
    var $Emails = array();

    function getUsername() {
        return $this->Username;
    }
}
```

Can you double-check your version?

Comment: Aha! I've been assuming that the command php -v was giving me the right answer. 
I included echo "'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();" in a separate file and got back
 "Current PHP version: 4.4.9-1+hw1".

Looks like a setup problem!
Thanks!